# SQL Where Clause Using AND

Tags: t-sql

I have a SQL query that looks like this in the `where` clause:

```
fs.iswaiver = 1       AND 
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), call_year) +'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), call_month) + '-' + '1' AS DATETIME) = '2018-03-31' AND 
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), call_year) +'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), call_month) + '-' + '1' AS DATETIME) = '2018-01-01'
```

I believe no results will come back because the call date has to be both

> '2018-03-01'

and

> '2018-01-01'

if I understand this `where` clause correctly. Is my understanding correct in this?

So if I have records that look like this:

```
call_year     call_month
     2018             03
     2018             01
```

Nothing will come back, correct?

Comment: `Nothing will come back, correct?` - Correct.

Comment: That's what I thought but I thought I was crazy. We need an IN clause then. Thank you. It's a shame you posted this as a comment instead of an answer, I could have marked that as correct ;)

Comment: I would have mixed feelings receiving credit for confirming that `(X = A) AND (X = B)` is always false for `A <> B`. Someone meant an `OR` somewhere, probably with parentheses somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps the intent was `'2018-01-01' <= DateFromParts( ... ) and DateFromParts( ... ) <= '2018-03-31'`, but someone got distracted.